# Hiding the bottom half of a table

Tags: html, css

I have a view in a webapp which looks like this, though generally with many more rows:

[image: Our current view]

Currently, all rows with a Status of 'Deprecated' are sorted to the bottom.  I want to update this view to hide these Status Deprecated, but allow them to be shown on request.  Is there any standard widget to do this?  Can anyone suggest something that doesn't look terrible?

Comment: Hi corykendall, welcome to UX.se! You questions seems a better fit for SO. Is there any user experience aspect of this proposed widget that you want to discuss?

Comment: @rk Hmm, I assumed the styling, positioning, and icon used for a widget will effect how likely users are to instantly understand what it means, but not feel like it's an eye-sore when they don't need it.  If this isn't a good fit for this site, feel free to move it.

Comment: While I agree with your point, you will need to present your idea for the design, to initiate the discussion in a constructive manner.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is implement a filter, which can display only the entries you want to see at this very moment. There may be a time when you want to see all entries, or filter the other way around. An example of this is the implementation of filter in Microsoft Excel (see image below), but also implemented in web environment especially in e-commerce sites.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make the table columns sortable (e.g. by clicking on the headings). Users that wanted to see Deprecated rows could "sort" them to the top.